# rails has_one association fields_for form not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Meeting model:

```
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :location, :class_name => "MeetingLocation", :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
```

Then I have a MeetingLocation model:

```
class MeetingLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :meeting
```

My new meeting form:

```
<%= form_for @meeting do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :location %>
  <%= fields_for :location do |l| %>
    Name <%= l.text_field :name %>
    Street <%= l.text_field :street %>
    City <%= l.text_field :city, :class => "span2" %>
    State <%= l.select :state, us_states, :class => "span1" %>
    Zipcode <%= l.text_field :zip, :class => "span1" %>
  <% end %>
```

When I view the new meeting form, the location fields are blank! I only see the location label but no other location fields. I've been looking for an explanation for the past 3 hours, found lot's of similar issues but no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: I restarted my browser and now i see the fields..but now when submitting the form instead of displaying "location_attributes" in the URL, it has, "location"=>{"name"=>"sdsds", "street"=>"sdsdsds",..} because of which location is not being automatically created, but a new meeting does get created.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The reason the location fields aren't displaying is that when you create a new meeting with `@meeting = Meeting.new`, this meeting does not yet have an associated MeetingLocation. If you call @meeting.location, you would get nil. For this reason, the form doesn't display fields for the location.

To fix this, you should call `@meeting.build_location` after creating a new meeting. That will associate the new meeting with a blank location.

EDIT: try changing `fields_for` to `f.fields_for`

Comment: Thanks but like i said after reopening the browser and restarting the server the fields did show up. Now my issue is that when i save a meeting, the location is not saved automatically as expected. I think the hint is in the URL since my location in the params does not say "location_attributes", it just says location.

Comment: See if the change in my EDIT fixes the problem.

Comment: Yes, a combination of both worked. 1) added f.fields_for 2) added @meeting.build_location. Thanks a lot cdesrosiers